# Pyside: как изменить размер кнопки?

Tags: python, pyqt4

Как изменить размер кнопки QtGui.QPushButton в слое QtGui.QGridLayout?
Пробовал .resize и .setGeometry  -  размер не меняет.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался

Comment: @Котик\_хочет\_кушать, есть смысл сделать ответом, несмотря на краткость формулировки, он полный.
@Obsidian, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте `sizePolicy`, поскольку кнопка у вас является частью лэйаута.